# .NET Core redirect to custom error pages from Startup.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have error 400 and 404 pages that I have created and want to use it for my application. I have declared this in my Startup.cs:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
    if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 400)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/Errors/AccessDenied.cshtml");
    }
});
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
    if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/Errors/NotFound.cshtml");
    }
});
```

Is this correct? When I tested it, I still get redirected back to the standard .net core error page.Am I missing something else?

Comment: May be cause you are getting 500 Status code and not 400/404

Comment: I'm getting a 404. The way I get it is from a link www.app.com/user/abcd1234

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can combine both using an `if .. else` construct like

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context => {
    if(context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 400)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/Errors/AccessDenied.cshtml");
    }
    else if (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 404)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("~/Views/Shared/Errors/NotFound.cshtml");
    }
});
```

Second, make sure you call `UseStatusCodePages` middleware before request handling middleware (for example, Static File Middleware and MVC Middleware).

I would suggest you to use either [`UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#usestatuscodepageswithredirect) (OR)
`UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute` instead redirecting explicitly

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. However, I am getting this url now when the error 404 happens. https://localhost:44365/Messages/AnnouncementAttachments/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/~/Views/Shared/Errors/NotFound.cshtml